# PCI Express interrupts in driver

Tags: linux-device-driver, kernel-module, pci-e

Hello iam developing PCIe communication between Xilinx FPGA and Intel PC...
I have written a kernel module(linux driver), i am using INTx interrupts.
I am facing the problem in interrupt handling....

**Before loading kernel module:**

from lspci: INT A-->11

from config read : INT A-->11

from /proc/interrupts : Nothing because irq not registerd

**After loading kernel module:**

from lspci: INT A-->16

from config read : INT A-->11

from /proc/interrupts : INT 11 registerd

When i run the program in FPGA it was sending interrupt to IRQ-16 and saying no body cared and it was disabled.

*in my module_init:*

```
request_irq(dev->gIrq, XPCIe_IRQHandler, IRQF_SHARED, gDrvrName, gDev));
```

*My irq handler:*

```
static irqreturn_t XPCIe_IRQHandler(int irq, void *dev_id, struct pt_regs *regs)
{    return IRQ_HANDLED; }
```

So anybody can say what the problem may be....

Answer (score 0):

You don't show where your `dev->gIrq` is set from, but your kernel module should be taking the interrupt number from the `struct pci_dev` associated with your device. See this comment in `include/linux/pci.h`:

```
struct pci_dev {
    ...
    /*
     * Instead of touching interrupt line and base address registers
     * directly, use the values stored here. They might be different!
     */
    unsigned int    irq;
```

Comment: And in newest kernel you are not supposed to do even that, but using `pci_alloc_irq_vectors()` & Co instead.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah Gil,
thanks for your reply..
in the code

```
 request_irq(dev->gIrq, XPCIe_IRQHandler, IRQF_SHARED, gDrvrName, gDev));
```

dev->gIrq is nothing but which i have taken from the pci_dev struct only.

and

Andy iam not using any MSI or MSI-X interrupts to use pci_alloc_irq_vectors().